# miniCode errors on IPod 5 ios 7.0.2

Tags: ios, sdk

In miniCode, applications work perfectly with the ios 3 and ios 6.1 sdks, but I am not able to get them to work with the ios 7.0 sdk.

My guess is that the ios 7.0 sdk is not supported, but I am wondering if there is any way I can get it to build properly.

Here are the errors I get when attempting to build and run an application:

First Error - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_memset", referenced from:
      -[HiAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in HiAppDelegate.m.o
      -[RootViewController loadView] in RootViewController.m.o

Second Error - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Third Error - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks in advance for any help possible!

Answer (score 0):

miniCode dev here. A lot of the time, this can be caused by not zipping up the SDK, transferring it, and then unzipping it on the device. Sometimes the symbolic links can get messed up, and this protects against that. (if my wording is bad, I meant that you SHOULD zip it up to transfer it)

If the problem keeps happening though, it may have to do with the iOS Toolchain, in which case you may have to ask coolstar about it. He tends not to reply, however, but you may get lucky. Just don't mention miniCode. He doesn't like miniCode.

Comment: After zipping it up and unzipping on the device itself, everything is working perfectly. Thanks for your help